# Appending Properties to Relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to append properties to a relationship in Neo4j. The following is as far as I could get so far in constructing a query:

`Match(n:Node),(m:Node) 
where n.Id=5 and m.Id=6 
create unique (n)-[rel:IS_RELATED]->(m) 
with rel as r 
set r += {Prop1:'Value1', Prop2:'Value2'}`

In the Neo4j manual it gives the following as an example and I tried to follow it to the best of my abilities.

`MATCH (peter { name: 'Peter' })
SET peter += { hungry: TRUE , position: 'Entrepreneur' }`

Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I am working with the Neo4jClient for .Net. What would be the fluent query to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

And use MERGE instead of create unique

```
Match(n:Node),(m:Node) 
where n.Id=5 and m.Id=6 
MERGE (n)-[rel:IS_RELATED]->(m) 
  ON CREATE SET rel += {Prop1:'Value1', Prop2:'Value2'}
```

Comment: I just tried to run that query and it does not run at all. Will Merge create a relation if it does not exist?